# very simple math destination and speed calculation

Tags: 2d, mathematics, movement, physics

My player goes to (destinationX, destinationY)

His position is: (x,y)

and the player has an update event

```
function update() {
 this.x = this.x + dx;
 this.y = this.y + dy;
}
```

what is the formula for dx and dy ?

```
dx = (destinationX-this.player.x)/this.speed;
dz = (destinationZ-this.player.z)/this.speed;
```

is "almost" good: it goes to the good direction, but problem is his speed.
It takes the same time to go from (0,0) to (10,10) than from (0,0) to (1000,1000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to normalize the direction vector, then multiply the result by your speed (since you want larger speeds to make you move faster). Something like:

```
dx = (destinationX-this.player.x).normalize() * this.speed;
dz = (destinationZ-this.player.z).normalize() * this.speed;
```

If you don't have access to a `normalize` function, you can create your own, the normalization of a vector follows this equation:

```
normalized_a = sqrt((a.x * a.x) + (a.y * a.y) + (a.z * a.z))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Byte56 is right. You only want a direction vector without any information about the distance to the target. You can get that by normalizing your vector to unit length. Do this:

```
 diffX = destinationX - this.player.x;
 diffY = destinationY - this.player.y;
 length = sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY); //Pythagorean law
 dx = diffX / length * this.speed; //higher speed is faster
 dy = diffY / length * this.speed;
```